# Сортировка дней недель по датам в файле CSV

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, обработка-данных, фильтрация

Пример CSV:

```
    Date,1,2,3,4,A,B
    2010-01-04,213.429998,214.499996,212.38000099999996,214.009998,123432400,27.727039
    2010-01-05,214.599998,215.589994,213.249994,214.379993,150476200,27.774976000000002
    2010-01-06,214.379993,215.23,210.750004,210.969995,138040000,27.333178000000004
    2010-01-07,211.75,212.000006,209.050005,210.58,119282800,27.28265
    2010-01-08,210.299994,212.000006,209.06000500000002,211.98000499999998,111902700,27.464034
```

Требуется отсортировать получившиеся значения только по понедельникам, а потом значения понедельников отсортировать от большего к меньшему. Например, есть даты в csv 2010.01.01.-31 - Понедельники здесь только 4, 11, 18, 25 число. Нужно оставить только строки с этими датами и указанным столбцом 'total'

```
    import os
    import glob
    import pandas as pd

    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

    file_mask = r'C:/Users/II/Downloads/*.csv'

    files = glob.glob(file_mask)

    for f in files:
        df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col='Date', encoding='latin1')
        df['total'] = df['1'] - df['2']
        
# теперь нужно отсортировать значения на основе дат по понедельникам.

        df = df.sort('total') # сортировка данных в столбце от большего к меньшему.
        
        new_fn = '{0[0]}_total{0[1]}'.format(os.path.splitext(f))
        df.to_csv(new_fn)
```

Comment: Я, честно говоря, вообще не понял ваш вопрос - `нужно отсортировать значения на основе дат по понедельникам`. Вы можете привести пример ваших данных (или кусок кода для их создания) и ожидаемый результат?

Comment: Вы можете также уточнить `значения понедельников отсортировать от большего к меньшему` - отсортировать по какому полю? По `total`?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы хотите отфильтровать (отбросить) все данные которые не попадают на понедельники? Еще одно уточнение: `столбец "1" - соответствует "Open", "2" - "High"`?

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример с классическими (оригинальными) именами столбцов для одного DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

a = wb.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', '2017-01-01')
# я так и не понял почему `total = Open - High`? ;)
a['total'] = a['Open'] - a['High']
# weekday: 0 - Понедельник, ..., 6 - Воскресенье    
a.loc[a.index.weekday == 0, 'total'].plot()
plt.show()
# сохранить график в файл...
plt.savefig('/path/to/filename.png')
```

PS сортировка по `total` ничего не даст (график останется таким же), т.к. значения будут отсортированы по оси `X`, т.е. по `Date`

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример отфильтрованных данных:

```
In [69]: a.loc[a.index.weekday == 0, 'total']
Out[69]:
Date
2017-01-09     0.250000
2017-01-23    12.059998
2017-01-30   -12.339966
2017-02-06     1.640015
2017-02-13     3.239990
Name: total, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

За изменение частоты даты отвечает функция resample и параметр Offset Aliases. Синтаксис resample простой, найдете здесь http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html?highlight=resample#pandas.DataFrame.resample. А список возможных параметров Offset Aliases здесь http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases.

Конкретно для понедельников, функция resample должна получить параметр "W-MON"

Comment: Мне кажется `resample` в данном случае (в  уточненном автором вопросе), не совсем подойдет т.к. после `resample()` данные будут агрегированы, а не отфильтрованы. Хотя, может автору именно это и надо???